# start usb-webcam via Nodejs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, webcam

I am working on my first raspberry-nodejs project, which I want to use a usb-webcam.
I've seen that there are a lot module for interactive with a webcam via node
and I have also seen the raspberry 'apt-get motion'... 
But does anyone know a package where I can turn the the camera on and off via a node-app. and then also define when to take pictures and where to store them?

Comment: If the answer was usefull please mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But does anyone know a package where I can turn the the camera on and
>   off via a node-app?

**node-v4l2camera** : https://github.com/bellbind/node-v4l2camera/ 
Capturing images from USB(UVC) webcam on Linux machines.

```
npm install v4l2camera
```

Once you got your `cam` configured, with `cam.start()` & `cam.stop()`

> and then also define when to take pictures and where to store them?

```
var v4l2camera = require("v4l2camera");
var cam = new v4l2camera.Camera("/dev/video0");
if (cam.configGet().formatName !== "MJPG") {
  console.log("NOTICE: MJPG camera required");
  process.exit(1);
}
cam.start();
cam.capture(function (success) {
  var frame = cam.frameRaw();
  require("fs").createWriteStream("result.jpg").end(Buffer(frame));
  cam.stop();
});
```

Comment: hey, i tried to us the module and I was able to start an stop the camera.
But i coldn't changet the format setting with the described why. Because my settings say ich have a different format and I want to change that to "MJPG". Did you ever made a change withe the settings? and did it work?

Comment: @bulb you are not being clear enough, the format is already "MJPG"... Have you checked the examples here : [https://github.com/bellbind/node-v4l2camera/tree/master/examples] ?  Check this one out maybe it helps : [https://github.com/bellbind/node-v4l2camera/blob/master/examples/capture-jpeg.js]

Comment: When check the settings via console.log it say's _`formatName = "YUYV"`_
I checked the examples, but that didn't help me. I even tried to change the width like it is described in the examples 
 (e.g. _cam.configSet({width: 320})_) 
, but when I then get the settings of the camera, nothing changed. And when I make an _console.log(cam.configSet({width: 320}))_
-> the I get 
   "_Camera { device: '..', formats [{object 1}, {object 2}, {object 3}.. ].. }_" 
which I always get if I didn't create an error for putting something wrong in the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Result...
I was able to get the "v4l2camera"-module working on my raspberry. 
But after a shutdown my raspberry goes back to the "YUYV"-Format.

So I always check the cam.config and I made it working with the "YUYV"-Format.
So now I am able to turn the camera on and take picture *year*

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cam.configSet({width: 1024, height: 768, format: 1195724874, formatName: "JPEG"});

if (cam.configGet().formatName !== "JPEG") {
  console.log("NOTICE: JPEG camera required");
  process.exit(1);
}
cam.start();
cam.capture(function (success) { <your code here> }
```